# The Open Closed Principle

Tags: oop, inheritance

Imagine I have a banking application with a base class called Account and many subclasses, e.g. Savings, Current. I have designed my application so that if I have a new account, say Checking, I can add it easily by not disturbing the other classes. This seems to follow the The Open Closed Principle.

But what happens if my customer decides that a detail of the Savings account needs changing? I'm not extending Savings, I want to change its 'calculateInterest()' method. Is the fact I have to modify Savings mean I violate The Open Closed Principle?

Comment: This might fit better under the programmers stack exchange. // While we're here, By what manner are you changing the calculate interest method? Are you adding to it or changing it completely? Maybe show how the method changes in some code.

Comment: Sorry man - it's a hypothetical scenario to understand the principle. And I mean changing the method to calculate the interest differently.

Comment: Do I manually move this to programmers stack exchange?

Comment: The Open Closed Principle does not mean you can't evolve your app. If the business logic changes, then you have to test everything again. Except if you want to keep both the new and the old behavior

Comment: I am not sure how to move it. I might just delete it and repost it over there. // In that situation I would say that if you do not want to violate the principle you need to implement code carefully. In your situation it seems like you initially calculate interest by doing `interest = m_balance * 0.0125` where you could've initially done `double rate {get; set;}; interest = m_balance * rate`. So I think the only way you might violate it, is if you don't implement very carefully.